# Colors Rendering Differently on Different Devices

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, android-resolution

Im setting the button state like

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_enabled="false" android:color="#FFF"></item>
    <item android:state_enabled="true" android:color="#000"></item>
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="false" android:color="#ffffff" />   
    <item android:color="#c7c7c7" />
</selector>
```

the problem is they are rendering differently on different devices like on Huwaei Ascend they are not that crisp but on Galaxy Device they are sharp and very crisp.

How can i make them look same on all devices.

Regards.

Comment: I guess it is because of the fact that they use different display technologies. There is not much that can be done.

Comment: what if use image as background will that be rendered in harmony?

Answer (score 1):

You have to live with it...
**Each device has a different display**.
Actually, Samsung's **Super AMOLED** displays are unbeatable (there's 1 led for every pixel, instead of a backlit LCD).
So, on devices with those displays the rendering will be brighter, while on LCDs it will be dimmer.